# NHibernate 3.1.0 : Select 1 subquery

Tags: nhibernate

How do I accomplish a subquery like "Select 1" in NHibernate 3.1.0?

In earlier versions, I know we used something like, 
.SetProjection(Projections.Constant("1")

In 3.1.0, 
.Select(1) is not possible, as Select(...) expects a Func<....> as a parameter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

there is an overload with `Select(params IProjection projections)` so you can write `.Select(Projections.Constant("1"))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample,

```
Session.QueryOver<Person>()
       .Where(p => P.Id == personId)
       .Select(Projections.Constant(1))
       .Take(1)
       .SingleOrDefault<int>();
```